# Date UTC issue with PST/EST

Tags: c#

I am trying to save date value to mysql DB, DB date column has UTCdatetime value, whenever the user selects time , it subtracts from the PST/EST/Mountain time, it works when i select PST & subtract -8 hrs, whenever i set MST- moutain time, -7, the date column doesn't save.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but if what you need is to store UTC dates, you don't need to manually add or subtract hours, there's a method for that:

```
var utcToday = DateTime.Today.ToUniversalTime();
```